# How to fetch data while ignoring some specific fields?

Tags: django, performance, django-models, django-queryset

With a model **Book** that uses `MarkDown` for a field called `content`, when I do the following query

```
Book.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('read')
```

The site becomes slow because of the content field, *I think the hard work occurs when Django tries to convert these fields to python object*. When I clean all the `content` field for each record and leave them blank, the query is pretty much faster.

In my case `content` field contains large text. To gain in performance, **How can I fetch data by ignoring a specific field?**

I want to ignore `content` field like:

```
Book.objects.filter(published=True)#.ignore_fields('content',).order_by('read')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`defer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#defer):

```
Book.objects.defer('content').filter(published=True).order_by('read')
```

Comment: How can I miss that from the doc!!!! anyway thank you. after reading `defer()` section from the doc, I think by using defer() after filter(), you're actually doing nothing, it will fetch `content`, it should be before filter() `Book.objects.defer('content').filter(published=True)`. Thanks a lot